# Get the date of the first connection with Facebook to my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, authentication

Is there a way to get the date when the user downloaded / installed  the first time an app via Facebook ? In my app , in the first launch you have to connect with Facebook. So I wonder , is there a way to get the date of this first connection. 
I found nothing interesting during my research on internet..
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here is multiple way to do this.

1.> You can store it on server end along with device UUID at login time.When you login first time with facebook via a remote connection , at server end you can put a check that this UUID is aready exist or not. If it is not then you can insert this UUID along with current date and time into server end database.

2.> You can store it locally in NSUserDefaults . Whenever you login with facebook , just check NSUserDefaults value via this code

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"firstTimeFaceBookLogin"])
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"firstTimeFaceBookLogin"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

NSLog(@"current date ===%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"firstTimeFaceBookLogin"]);
```

Now NSUserDefaults value any where in your app via firstTimeFaceBookLogin key. But if you delete your application from device then this NSUserDefaults would be clear and again create a store new value after installing it in your device.

I hope you understand it. Please let me inform if you still having any confusion. Thanks